# Get value of radio checked in semantic ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I am trying to get the value of the checkbox after form is submitted, but nothing is being output. There is no documentation on how to do that on the website.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui.radio.checkbox').checkbox();

    $('#formOne').submit(e => {
       let num = $('#radio').val();
       console.log(num);
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/semantic.min.js"></script>

<form class="ui form" id="formOne">
    <div class="field" id="radio" >
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" value="one" name="number">
            <label>One</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input type="radio" value="two" name="number">
            <label>Two</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The element with the id of radio is the div around the radios, no the radio's themselves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find the selected radio, not the div around the radios.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ui.radio.checkbox').checkbox();

$('#formOne').submit(e => {
      let num = $('#radio').find('[name="number"]:checked').val();
      console.log(num);
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/semantic.min.js"></script>

<form class="ui form" id="formOne">
  <div class="field" id="radio" >
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" value="one" name="number">
      <label>One</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" value="two" name="number">
      <label>Two</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ui.radio.checkbox').checkbox();

$('#formOne').submit(e => {
      var num = $("input[name='number']:checked").val();
      console.log(num);

      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

And your HTML is:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/semantic.min.js"></script>

    <form class="ui form" id="formOne">
      <div class="field" id="radio" >
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
          <input type="radio" value="one" name="number">
          <label>One</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui radio checkbox">
          <input type="radio" value="two" name="number">
          <label>Two</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this :

```
<form class="ui form" id="formOne">
  <div class="field" id="radio" >
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" value="one" name="number">
      <label>One</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
      <input type="radio" value="two" name="number">
      <label>Two</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ui.radio.checkbox').checkbox();

$('#formOne').submit(e => {
       let num = $('[name="number"]:checked').val();
       console.log(num);
       e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aen7v3jp/16/)